# visual example of passing object into another objects constructer?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, instantiation

Im learning about threads and one example of instatiating a Thread was

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable) 
{ 
code goes here
}
```

My question is what does that exactly mean to have an new class passed into another class's constructor? What are the implications/benefits of doing this?

Comment: Your example seems off, as you'd likely be creating an anonymous inner Runnable class here, not an anonymous inner Thread class, as you're doing.

Comment: ok sure but that doesnt answer my question. whts the benefit of passing objects through another objects constructor?

Comment: The question is the same as "what's the benefit of creating an anonymous inner class" which is all that you're doing (although as I noted above, you're doing it incorrectly). It's fine for small one-off classes that are not re-used and require no new behaviors or states.

Comment: no my code is correct. how is it supposed to look?

Comment: Your code won't compile as your Runnable has no `()`, and no curly braces associated with *the Runnable*. Better would be something like this: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/7vmYb9wW). The compiler is strict and unforgiving and so details matter. Believe me.